# Compare two List<Object[]> efficiently in Java

Tags: java, list

I have two `List<Object[]>` and I need to compare the values inside that and create a final list with just unique values.

Ex:

```
List<Object[]> list1 has n rows of object list with 5 columns
  [[val1,val2,val3,val4,val5],[val1_,val2_,val3_,val4_,val5_]]

List<Object[]> list2 has n rows of Object list with 4 columns
  [[val3_,val4_,val5_,val6_],[val2,val3,val4,val5]]
```

The composition of second to fifth column of elements in `Object` array in the `list1` might match with the elements in `Object` array in the `list2`. When all those columns matches, that should not be repeated in the new `List`. Or, instead of using a new list, I can just update the contents in `list1` itself. If `list2` has something unique that `list1` does not have, I shall add it to the list. Unfortunately, the output of my program will only result in `List<Object[]>`. Could someone please tell me how I can make this comparison done efficiently?

Comment: What have you written thus far? You also say `n` rows, but what is the highest number of `n`? You may be pre-optimizing... Make an effort on the comparison and do a benchmark, then see where you need to improve, if you even need to.

Comment: are you saying you want a unique union of values? If so, perhaps you can just add them to a HashSet, then construct an ArrayList with the HashSet, this would give you a unique set of values (if I understand the question). What are the objects?

Comment: @markg, HashSet won't work, because java arrays don't implement equals.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yep, i missed that, thanks. The op could put the array in an object and implement equals, then the idea may work.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have an `equals` or `hashcode` method, but `List`s do, so you can use a `List` as the key to a `HashMap`.

Write a method to generate a `List<Object>` to use as a key:

- for your 5-element list, it'll be `new ArrayList(array).subList(1,array.length)`
- for your 4-element list, it'll be `new ArrayList(array)`

Then:

```
Map map = new HashMap<List<Object>, Object[]>();
for(array : fourColumnArrays) {
     map.put( keyForFourElements(array), array);
}
for(array : fiveColumnArrays) {
     map.put( keyForFiveColumnArrays(array), array);
}
```

`map` now contains the arrays you need.